# Gitlab runner faces ssl certificate problem

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab

I am using the gitlab community runners to build my code.

All of a sudden I face this issue in the pipeline of my project:

"fatal: unable to access .... SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

This is the log of the runner.

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/my-org/my-repository-name/.git/
Created fresh repository.
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-us-east1-d.ci-gateway.int.gprd.gitlab.net:8989/my-org/my-repository-name.git.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

As far as I remember I did not change anything about my ci pipeline in the last period (between when it did work and now, when it does not work anymore).

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had a gitlab runner ENV VAR named `CI_PROJECT_PATH` with value "my-org/my-repo.git".
It never caused problems before.
But now I've changed it to `my-org/my-repo` and the problem is fixed